# How do I install vmware workstation 11? (the install window won't appear)

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I keep having a problem where my old VMware workstation (10.0) steals my alt key. So I thought I'd give the new v 11 a trial, but it won't start the install workflow instead I get this:

```
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-11.1.2-2780323.x86_64.bundle
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module": libunity-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am on Trusty.
From suggestions I found around google I have tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-2.4-dev
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines-murrine
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

Also both unity-gtk2-module and unity-gtk3-module 's are installed from apt.

Another update: TOP shows me this:

```
8415 root      20   0  194520  57732  19944 R  99.7  0.2   3:12.77 /tmp/vmis.bK5DY4/install/vmware-installer/vmis-launcher /tmp/vmis.bK5DY4/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer.py --set-setting vmware-installer libconf /tmp/vmis.bK5DY4/install/vmware-installer/lib/libconf --install-component /tmp/vmis.bK5DY4/install
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: 14.04 LTS release. Something else I noticed, I can't upgrade my current vmware either...

Comment: Can you post the full path of the Unity GTK libraries?

Comment: Where do I get that from?

Comment: Same to me, 14.04, installer for Vmware 12 opens, but previous versions (8, 10¸ 11) won't.

Comment: BTW, VmWare 12 shows the same messages, but the window opens.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the modules installed, (Note: As per [A.B](https://askubuntu.com/users/367165/a-b)).  Here is how I installed VMWare 11:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo su -c "apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox gcc build-essential"
sudo su
chmod +x ./VMware*11*.bundle
./Vmware*11*.bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing file `libunity-gtk-module.so` is part of the packages `unity-gtk3-module` and `unity-gtk2-module`

Therefore install the packages via

```
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk3-module
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk2-module
```

Comment: I already have both modules installed.

Comment: You should note that in your question.